# Tensorflow 2: how to connect two layers from saved models?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have two saved models. I want to load and connect the output from model-1 to the input for model-2:

```
# Load model1
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model1.h5')

# Load model2
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model2.h5')

# get the input/output tensors
model1Output = model1.output
model2Input = model2.input

# reshape to fit
x = Reshape((imageHeight, imageWidth, 3))(model1Output)

# how do I set 'x' as the input to model2?

# this is the combined model I want to train
model = models.Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model2.output)
```

I know you can set the Input when you instantiate a `Layer` by passing the input as a parameter (`x = Input(shape)`). But how do you set the `Input`, in my case `x`, on an existing layer? I've looked at the documentation for the `Layer` class [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer), but I can't see this mentioned?

**Edit:**

Adding the summaries of both models...

Here is the top of `model1`:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 304, 304, 16) 4624        activation_14[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 304, 304, 32) 0           concatenate[3][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 304, 304, 16) 4624        dropout_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 304, 304, 16) 64          conv2d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)      (None, 304, 304, 16) 0           batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 304, 304, 10) 170         activation_16[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
```

And here is the input of `model2`:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 299, 299, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 149, 149, 32) 864         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 149, 149, 32) 128         block1_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1_act (Activation)   (None, 149, 149, 32) 0           block1_conv1_bn[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 147, 147, 64) 18432       block1_conv1_act[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I need the output of `conv2d_18` in `model1` to be fed as the input to `block1_conv1` in `model2`.

Comment: so,you want the last layer of model1 `block1_conv2` to be the input of model2,can you post summary of model2 too?

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly. I corrected an error in the summary too. What you see now is correct.

Comment: output from model1 has shape `(None, 304, 304, 10)` and input of model2 has shape `(None, 299, 299, 3)`,the channels are 10 and 3 respectively

Comment: Yes, I've added a Reshape Layer to convert the Dimensions: `x = Reshape((imageHeight, imageWidth, 3))(model1Output)` (see code). But I don't know how to set the input for `model2` to be `x`.

Comment: I think what you can do is to skip the first input layer of model2  and combine the ouput of model1 to model2 `block1_conv1` layers by adding some additional pooling layers between two models

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I don't know how to connect a layer to `block1_conv1`.

Comment: I don't think you can reshape in this situation,it will throw error

Comment: Do you know how I would connect a layer to `block1_conv1` anyway (say if the no. of channels were the same)? I don't know how to do this already instantiated layers.

Comment: You can use `model2.layers[1:]` to skip the first layer,but you need to have an additional pooling layer between the models to fit size

Comment: I retrieved the tensor object with `conv2DLayer = model2.get_layer('block1_conv1')` but I don't know how to pass `x` or any other tensor to it? How do I connect a Layer to it?

Comment: `model2.get_layer()` retrieve the output from one layer

Comment: How do I actually connect the tensor to it though? I can't do `x = Conv2D()(x)` because the return value from `model2.get_layer('block1_conv1')` is already instantiated. That's all I need to know.

Comment: It's complaining that: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` when I try `x = model2.layers[1:](x)`

Comment: my bad `for  i,layer in enumerate(model2.layers[1:]):
        x = layer(x)` you have to iterate through each layer,also beware of layers name they should be unique for both model and it;s better you write your own layer according to the models

Comment: That's working but I've no idea why. Strange that it's necessary to iterate through each layer or how you can seemingly do `x = layer(x)` when it's already instantiated, but it works. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it for you, thanks!

Comment: I will post the answer, `model.layers` get all the layers like a list so you have to iterate through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have two models, model1 and model2,you can pass the output from one model to input to the other model,

you can do in this way:

here, `model2.layers[1:]` the index `1` is chosen specific for your question to skip the first layer and propagate the input through its 2nd layer of the model.

between models we may require extra convolution layers to fit the shape of input

```
def mymodel():
  # Load model1
  model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model1.h5')

  # Load model2
  model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model2.h5')

  x = model1.output

  #x = tf.keras.models.layers.Conv2D(10,(3,3))(x)

  for  i,layer in enumerate(model2.layers[1:]):
        x = layer(x)
  model = keras.models.Model(inputs=model1.input,outputs= x)

  return model
```

Note: Anyone with better solution can edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found another way to do this which makes more sense to me at least:

```
# Load model1
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model1.h5')

# Load model2
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/model2.h5')

# reduce the 10 dim channels to 1 dim 
newModel2Input = tf.math.reduce_max(model1.output, axis=-1)

# convert to 3 dims to match input expected by model2 
newModel2Input = Reshape((299, 299, 3))(newModel2Input)  

# this is the combined model I want to train
model = models.Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model2(newModel2Input))
```